# smartirc4net listens forever, can't exit thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, irc

I have a IRC bot that uses the smartirc4net library. I have run into an issue where the bot is listening for commands and I want the thread it is running on to exit. The `Listen()` command blocks forever. If I use `ListenOnce()` I can put the call inside of a `While(!ShouldExit)` loop, but I have to wait for the bot for something to trigger the `ListenOnce()`.

```
    protected void irc_OnConnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        irc.Login(configuration.IRCNick, configuration.IRCNick);

        while (!_shouldDisconnect)
        {
            irc.ListenOnce();
        }

        irc.Disconnect();
    }
```

As a work around, when the bot is issued a disconnect command from the parent thread, it sends itself a message:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Used by the parent thread to disconnect the bot
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public void Disconnect()
    {
        _shouldDisconnect = true;

        irc.SendMessage(SendType.Message, irc.Nickname, "EXIT YOU STUPID BOT");
    }
```

This triggers the `ListenOnce()` event to loop back through the while loop, then successfully disconnect.
Am I approaching this incorrectly? Is there a cleaner approach for getting the bot to disconnect immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that this is a bug in the latest code, confirmed with meebey over at https://github.com/meebey/SmartIrc4net/issues/4